# Get closest date from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need to get the closest date to current date from a MySQL table.

This is my table:

```
id        | date          | name
1         | 2012-10-29    | test
2         | 2009-11-31    | test
```

So if the query was run today, it would return `1         | 2012-10-29    | test`

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  your_table 
ORDER BY 
  ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this only give dates in the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 date from table
where date > now()
order by date desc
```

Comment: this only give dates in the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(`date`, NOW()));
```

Returns:

```
'1', '2012-10-29 00:00:00', 'test'
```